# Rest API -> passing json string as parameter value

Tags: json, rest

Is it the recommended way to pass a JSON string as a parameter value in a REST API?
This is the data which I am trying to send :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/v1/product/?productName=&metrics={"memory":2,"disk_space":10}

Here, is it ok to pass the value of metrics as JSON value?

Initially, I tried passing the metrics JSON value in the body. As it is not supported/recommended standard I have removed it.

Comment: Maybe it will help you http://dotnetcodeforu.blogspot.com/2013/12/pass-json-string-data-to-rest-service.html

Answer (score 4):

> Is it the recommended way to pass a JSON string as a parameter value in a REST API?

REST is an architectural style and it doesn't enforce (or even define) any standards for *passing JSON string as a parameter value*.

---

If you want to send JSON in the query string, you must [URL encode](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) it first:

```
/v1/products?productName=&metrics=%7B%22memory%22%3A2%2C%22disk_space%22%3A10%7D
```

Alternativelly, you could redesign the parameters to be like:

```
/v1/products?productName=&metrics.memory=2&metrics.diskSpace=10
```

If the URL gets *too long* (or the query gets *too complex* to be expressed in the query string), you may want to consider [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) instead of [`GET`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1), and then send the JSON in the request payload:

```
POST /v1/products/search HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "productName": "foo",
  "metrics": {
    "memory": 2,
    "diskSpace": 10
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Cassio for your input

Answer (score 0):

Sending JSON values in `GET` request is not recommended. You can do it but metrics json can be long and anybody can read the content.

You should use `POST` request to send parameters such as `productName` and `metrics` in the body.

You should refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Actually this should be GET request because it is not inserting any data to database so no issue with  the reading the content by others .

Comment: Other issues with GET, including string length limitations. So no, GET should not be used. POST is almost always better and more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

For use Content-Type  Application Json Please use below line

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\n\t\"lastName\":\"gaurav.sablok@agarwalpackers.com\"\n}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

This is used with "RestSharp" name spaces

Comment: gaurav.sablok@agarwalpackers.com you can edit and put your values